# Formulário - Pegar dados com PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

Sou iniciante nessa parte de criação de sites, estou fazendo um site onde terá um formulário de cadastro, e eu quero que esse cadastro vá para um banco de dados, ou uma página que pode ter acesso à todos os cadastros efetuados. Tentei fazer o formulário em HTML, referenciando ao PHP, mas ao enviar pelo botão, o usuário é redirecionado a pagina PHP, e eu não quero que isso aconteça, quero que ao clicar no botão Enviar, apenas envie esses dados para o Banco, sem ir para nenhuma outra página, como posso resolver o problema? Teria que fazer o formulário já em PHP?

Comment: Até onde eu sei, se tu fizer o form já em php e não informar o caminho, ele vai processar na mesma pagina (arquivo), não sei se é o que procura.

Comment: Não tem como fazer o formulário em PHP. No máximo fazer o PHP gerar o HTML, mas o resultado será sempre HTML e isso não fará diferença no seu problema. O que você precisa é JavaScript, com requisição AJAX. Pesquise sobre isso.

Comment: Você pode fazer o formulario no arquivo php para dar um post ou get no proprio arquivo ou usar o ajax  como o @AndersonCarlosWoss disse.